# OpenERP - Smsclient module

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I try to install this module on Odoo https://apps.openerp.com/apps/7.0/smsclient/ but it fails during the installation, so i can't even try it as an sms solution for Odoo. Did anybody manage to install it? Or can suggest me another module to send sms via Odoo?

Here is the trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 500, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 517, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 283, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 280, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 733, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 376, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 948, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 450, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_install, context=context)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 497, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.new(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 324, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 358, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 263, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 182, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 118, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 899, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 985, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 851, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](self.cr, rec, n, mode=mode)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 765, in _tag_record
    id = self.pool['ir.model.data']._update(cr, self.uid, rec_model, self.module, res, rec_id or False, not self.isnoupdate(data_node), noupdate=self.isnoupdate(data_node), mode=self.mode, context=rec_context )
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1051, in _update
    res_id = model_obj.create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 264, in create
    context=context)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 332, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3977, in create
    record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 235, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 464, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 4158, in _create
    recs._validate_fields(vals)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 235, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 1299, in _validate_fields
    raise ValidationError('\n'.join(errors))
ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Element '<field name="mobile">' cannot be located in parent view

Error context:
View `ir.actions.server.form.inherit`
[view_id: 345, xml_id: n/a, model: ir.actions.server, parent_id: 13]" while parsing /home/user/odoo/odoo/openerp/addons/smsclient/serveraction_view.xml:4, near
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_server_statistics_graph">
            <field name="name">ir.actions.server.form.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">ir.actions.server</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_server_action_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <data><field name="mobile" position="after">
                    <field name="sms_server" invisible="1"/>
                    <field name="sms_template_id" domain="[('sms_template','=',True)]" attrs="{'required':[('state','=','sms')]}"/>
                </field>
                <field name="sms" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute> 
                    <attribute name="required">0</attribute>
                    <attribute name="attrs">{}</attribute>
                </field>
            </data></field>
        </record>
```

Comment: can you post server trace-back?

Comment: @Odedra there you go...thanks

Comment: In odoo, `mobile field` is remove from the base module with object `ir.actions.server` so you need to customize it.

Comment: @Odedra I remove that field and sms field fires the exception now